# A better approach to recursion?

Tags: swift

I built this code sample in Swift Playgrounds as a proof-of-concept for part of a larger project that I'm working on. What I need to do is pass in a series of options (represented by optionsArray or testArray) where each int is the number of options available. These options will eventually be built into 300+ million separate PDFs and HTML files. The code currently works, and puts out the giant list of possibilities that I want it to.

My question is this: Is there a better approach to handling this kind of situation? Is there something more elegant or efficient? This is *not* something that will be run live on an app or anything, it will run from a command line and take all the time it needs, but if there is a better approach for performance or stability I'm all ears.

Things I already know: It can't handle a value of 0 coming out of the array. The array is a constant, so it won't happen by accident. The way the code down the line will handle things, 0 is a nonsensical value to use. Each element represents the number of options available, so 2 is essentially a Boolean, 1 would be *false* only. So if I needed placeholder elements for future expansion, they would be a value of 1 and show up as a 0 in the output.

Also, the final product will not just barf text to the console as output, it will write a file in the `permutationEnding()` function based on the `currentOptions` array.

```
let optionsArray: [Int] = [7,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
let testArray: [Int] = [7,2,3,2]
var currentOptions: [Int] = []
var outputString: String = ""
func buildPermutations(array: Array<Int>) {
    currentOptions.removeAll()
    permutationRecursion(array: array, index: 0)
}
func permutationRecursion(array: Array<Int>, index: Int) {
    for i in 1 ... array[index] {
        currentOptions.append(Int(i-1))
        if array.count > (index + 1) {
            permutationRecursion(array: array, index: index + 1)
        } else {
            permutationEnding()
        }
        currentOptions.removeLast()
    }
}
func permutationEnding() {
    for i in 1 ... currentOptions.count { // Output Elements
        outputString += String(currentOptions[i-1])
    }
    outputString += "\n" // Goes after output elements closing bracket.
}
// buildPermutations(array: optionsArray) 
buildPermutations(array: testArray)
print(outputString)
```

Thoughts?

Comment: What's exactly are you trying to do? Build a list of permutations using some predefined-options?

Comment: Essentially, yes. I have an enterprise app that allows people to go through an interview process, and some of the answers they give trigger more information to be put into a PDF that is dynamically generated for them. Due to the nature of the business I work for, the audit risk for running custom code (PHP, etc) on a server is oppressive, and the client-side PDF generation options that use JavaScript are inadequate at best. I've been asked to find a solution that uses neither for a web version similar to the app.

Comment: So, I'm going to have to pump HTML templates into this thing (much like I do with the existing app), and have it put out *all* of the possibilities as premade PDFs. Eventually, I will also have to make it build the entire decision tree as HTML, so it works like the app does. Thee outputs will be something like 50101010011...etc.pdf when it's done. It's ridiculous, but it allows us to have every option without server-side tech being used. Regulators can make life strange.

Comment: Yes i understand these regulators can be a pain in the neck. I profiled your code in Release build, took 17ms on my iMac so it's not worth optimizing further. How big can `testArray` get?

Comment: testArray is just for testing the code in Playgrounds. The real array is optionsArray. That one is a beast so i made a little one just to figure things out with. My guess is optionsArray will take a lot more time. I haven't played with Release build, is it part of the Xcode package? Sadly, I'm PC at home so I have no access to the fancy stuff. I'm all iPad until I hit the office on Tuesday.

Comment: I've got bad news for you  @C.Brackett , finding all permutations of an array of 26 items is not computationally tractable. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=26+permute+26

Comment: You're looking at `8.388×10^16 TB (terabytes)` total memory needed to store `403291461126605635584000000` permutations of 26 8 byte `Int`s.

Comment: @Alexander Does it help that not all of the ints are that big? The optionsArray I provided is the actual number of possibilities. The number I came up with is 7*3*2^24 or 352,321,536 since each int only needs to be evaluated for the value that it contains. It still a big number even if you consider that each file will have a fairly small size. Something like 35 gig if each file is only 100k in size. My math could be way off though. I figured that a build involving PDFs and the HTML tree leading to them could approach 50gig easily. Again, my math could be waaaaaay off.

Comment: I misunderstood your problem. So if we take "test array" as an example: `[7,2,3,2]` means there are 4 "parameters". The first is one of 7 choices, the second is one of 2, then 3, then 2. Thus there are `7*2*3*2 = 84` ways to chose them?

Comment: Indeed! Which, luckily, is the same number of outputs I get when i run the sample code. The optionsArray was simply too big for me to abuse Playgrounds with so I made a smaller one to test on it. The big boy just started grinding away with no end in sight. Might take a while even on my desktop.

Comment: When you say "permutations", are you talking about a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) or actually [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured out what you're trying to do. You want a string output of every possible integer combination that could map all possible routes on the decision tree.

I got it down to four or five lines.

```
let n = testArray.count // for readability
let products = ([Int](1...n)).map({testArray[$0..<n].reduce(1, *)})

// products is the cross product of element i + 1 to  element n of the array for all i in the array

let zipped = zip(testArray, products)

for i in 0..<testArray.reduce(1, *) { // this reduce is the cross product of the whole array

    let treePath = zipped.map(){ String(i / $0.1 % $0.0) }.joined()
    outputString += treePath + "\n"
}
```

One more edit: I think this might be faster with some fancy matrix operations like NumPy. I wonder if the Accelerate framework could do some magic for you, but I have not worked with it.

edit: I was curious so I timed it with this test array

```
let testArray: [Int] = [7,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,2]
```

The recursive function in the question was: 132.56 s

The zip-map here was: 14.44 s

And it appears to be exponential as I add elements to the test array.

Comment: That's a beauty! I'll have to do a bit of homework to understand exactly how it's doing the work. I'll look into NumPy too and see what I can find there. Thanks for the insight and different idea about how to approach the problem.

Comment: NumPy is a Python Library that can do operations on a whole matrix/series very quickly. I've read that the Accelerate framework can do similar things in ObjC/Swift. Out of curiosity, Is this for computerizing clinical practice guidelines / medical history taking?

Comment: It's not. It's for highly customizable accounts and ancillary services at a financial institution. The interview process and its resulting answers (the array) essentially form a roadmap for the account application requirements and recommended product/services associated with it.